Get Some Tweets From Specific User On Twitter - Twitter API
I am a Udacity Student, And I have to do a project that gathers data from Twitter from a specific username. But every time I try to gather it the API gives me this error message.
consumer_key = os.getenv('consumer_key')
consumer_secret = os.getenv('consumer_secret')
access_token = os.getenv('access_token')
access_secret = os.getenv('access_secret')

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Screen name of the account you want to fetch tweets from
screen_name = 'dog_rates'

# Fetch tweets
tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=1, tweet_mode="extended")
# tweet = api.get_status("1810340805602693232") #  I tried this also with the same error.

This is the error message:
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

Note:

I am sure of my credintials
I use the free plan of the twitter API and can't buy the basic plan for this project
If there is any solution rather that gathering by this method and do the job ok

